# Arrays - static method to return sum, but nothing is returned

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Create a Java program that reads 10 numbers from the console Scanner
input = new Scanner(System.in); .Store the numbers as Floats in the array. Create static methods to perform the following actions on the array and returns the result.Add all the items in the array and return the result. Name this method"add".

So this is my code, but when the user inputs the 10 numbers, nothing is returned. Any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    float[] myArray = new float[10];        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("please enter number");
        myArray[(i)] = input.nextFloat();
    }
}

public static float add(float[] array) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: where are you calling it ? I don't see that code ?

Comment: your not calling your add function , call it after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    float[] myArray = new float[10];        
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("please enter number");
        myArray[(i)] = input.nextFloat();
    }
    System.out.println(add(myArray)); // need to make this call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of for loop you need to call the `add` method.

```
System.out.println(add(myArray));
```

Comment: missing a semi colon ... at the end of the statement :P